# calling onDraw method on click of a button

Tags: android

shapesview is a custom view.what i want is that the ondraw method to be called on click of a button.
view:

```
 public class ShapeView extends View {

Paint cPaint;
Random r=new Random();
public static int n=3;
public ShapeView(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context,attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    cPaint = new Paint();
    cPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);


}
public ShapeView(Context context){
    super(context);
}
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    Log.e("LineView", Integer.toString(n));
    int n1=1;
    while(n1<=n)
    {
        Log.d("draw","n= " +n);
        int x=r.nextInt(canvas.getWidth()-50);
        int y=r.nextInt(canvas.getHeight()-200);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 10, cPaint);
        n1++;
    }
}
public void nextshape(int n)
{
    this.n=n;
    Log.d("n","n= " +n);
    invalidate();

}

}
```

the nextshape method is called on click of a button that is in the activity on which this custom view is added.Here is the code for it.

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.next_button:
        i=i+1;
        Log.d("shape","i= "+i);
        shape.nextshape(i);
        break;

    }
```

I am adding the view onto the activity using the xml file.
The onDraw method runs only 2 or 3 times.and after that nothing happens.what is the problem in this code?

Comment: What do you mean it only runs 2 or 3 times?  It only draws 2 or 3 circles?  That's expected-  you're looping until n1=3.  That old circles get erased?  That's expected-  you're calling invalidate, that erases all the old data on screen.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan i mean that when i click the button for the first 2-3 times the value of n increases and the number of circles increase.but after that the when i click the button nothing happens.